# javascript getBoundingClientRect() values are wrong for dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript

Not able to find an answer on wide web so posting the question here.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

When the user scrolls to the very bottom of the page get the latest dynamically loaded element's bottom value and use it to find out if it is time to load another one.

The math is simple:

```
if (element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight)
   loadAnotherElement();
```

> window.innerHeight is 955px

**The problem:**

On initial load the the first element's bottom value is `905px` which is fine and trigger the function to load another one, but after the second one is loaded in the bottom value is `1389px` which will never trigger the `loadAnotherElement` function.

I am not able to post full code as it is too complicated so hope the above will be enough to understand.

**EDIT**

Managed to create a proper [test case](https://jsfiddle.net/ebmkhjkg/2/)

Comment: I am not seeing this issue in a simple test case: https://jsfiddle.net/ebmkhjkg/1/ - So your issue is probably not javascript doing something unexpected, but maybe your CSS doing something to elements?

Comment: @somethinghere it took me ages to recreate the problem in jsfiddle but managed in the end. The problem is that elements inside the parent are shifting up to the previous parent. Don't even know how to explain it properly :) please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/ebmkhjkg/2/ and you will see the problem

Comment: I am not seeing the issue, more elements are being added as you hit the bottom. The shifting seems to be more of a CSS issue than anything else... There's occasional holes but it works fine (I am using Safari Technology Preview but i don't think it makes a difference).

Comment: I don't have safari to test if there are any differences. Tested in Firefox and Chrome, both seem to have the same behavior - when the second batch of elements is loaded the third one doesn't load anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the JS fiddle you posted the reason it was not recognising the correct height is because your inner elements are floating. A float does not contribute to the height of the parent element, so I will suggest the following solution:

```
article:after {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}
```

I have also cleaned up the fiddle a bit an removed the unnecessary parts so it's easier to see where the mistake was (there was no advantage to the table style displayed before and after on your section).

```js
var last = document.querySelector('article');
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if(last.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight){
        var newElement = last.cloneNode(true);
        last.parentNode.appendChild(newElement);
        last = newElement;
    }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

/* I have removed a bit of CSS that I think didn't really do anything at all. */

article {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

/* This will create an element that will clear past the floats, stretching your article to the correct encapsulating size */

article:after {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}

/* Some correction so they all stay neatly in line */

div {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1.5%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
}

div:nth-child(3n-2){ background: #666; }
div:nth-child(3n-1){ background: #888;  }
div:nth-child(3n){ background: #222; }
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <!-- I made these 6 divs so they neatly pack six in an article. -->
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

#### Update

If you want the elements to neatly stay in line, why bother wrapping them in seperate elements? Simple create the elements as new siblings which will push its final size:

```js
var section = document.querySelector('section');
var article = document.querySelector('article');
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if(section.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight){
        section.appendChild(article.cloneNode(true));
    }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

/* I have removed a bit of CSS that I think didn't really do anything at all. */

section {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

/* This will create an element that will clear past the floats, stretching your article to the correct encapsulating size */

section:after {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}

/* Some correction so they all stay neatly in line */

div {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1.5%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
}

div:nth-child(3n-2){ background: #666; }
div:nth-child(3n-1){ background: #888;  }
div:nth-child(3n){ background: #222; }
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <!-- I made these 7 divs for illustrations sake. -->
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: I will never have 6 child elements in parent. It can be 7, 8, 15 or any number so `article` element can't have `display: inline-block`. The requirement is to not have any gaps (where child element should be) between the two `article` elements

Comment: Why not? Why, instead of adding an entire block, don't you just add more `divs` inside your article?

Comment: That could be a solution which I have already thought about, but the paging of the website would not work in that case. The `article` element is a page, but the paging can be turned off and the infinite scroll turned on and that's when the problem arises. I might go with your second solution and rework a code as it seems to solve the problem I have at the moment. Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: That seems like something you can work around. Its best to find a solution that doesn't feel so hacky. You could actually still do the article element, the only reason I changed your CSS was to keep it simple so the solution seems simple, but it shouldn't make a difference. Check my update to the post to see how you could do it. In this case, by the way, the article section styling can be kept. Just check for the bottom of your section, and add articles inside it.

Comment: Probably I am just over complicating things - spend far too much time looking at the some code over and over again :) Thanks again :)

Comment: @Morpheus I totally get that, happens all the time. Certainly after you start adding things and then fearing that if you take them away it will break something. I think its best to start from scratch sometimes instead of trying to fix something, as fixing something will take long but starting from scratch could make you look at the problem in a different way :) Cheers!